# Sqlite Delete worked return ok but not cancel

Tags: bash, sqlite

Hi  i have this function in bash

```
_Sqlite_Delete_Row(){
    local database_name="$1"
    local NameTable="$2"
    local column_names="$3"
    local row_to_delete="$4"
    
    if echo "${column_names}" | grep -q "|"; then
        # Costruzione della query SQL
        local query="DELETE FROM $NameTable WHERE "
        local columns=($(echo "$column_names" | tr '|' ' '))
        local values=($(echo "$row_to_delete" | tr '|' ' '))
        for ((i=0; i<${#columns[@]}; i++)); do
            if [[ $i -eq 0 ]]; then
                query+="${columns[i]}='${values[i]}'"
            else
                query+=" AND ${columns[i]}='${values[i]}'"
            fi
        done
        echo "La query è: $query"
        if sqlite3 "$database_name" "$query"; then
            echo "Cancellazione Row riuscita."
            return 0
        else
            echo "Errore durante la cancellazione del row nel database."
            return 1
        fi
    
    else
        local query="DELETE FROM $NameTable WHERE $column_names='$row_to_delete';"
        #echo "SQL stringa $query"
        if sqlite3 "$database_name" "$query"; then
            echo "Cancellazione Row riuscita."
            return 0
        else
            echo "Errore durante la cancellazione del row nel database."
            return 1
        fi
    fi  
}

my_string="Symbol|ValMedPerc|HowZero|ValRepeat|HowTrade|OpenPriceTrade|OkorNot|GainPercent|DataOpen|DataClose"
my_array_val="LUNAUSDT|13.89|1.0|2.00|20|1.4299|0|1||"

#_Sqlite_Delete_Row "BinCexExchangeInfo.db" "ROBOTEST"  "symbol" "de"  
_Sqlite_Delete_Row "BinCexExchangeInfo.db" "ROBOTEST" "$my_string" "$my_array_val"
```

this is a database https://mega.nz/file/r9Mj2RqK#9oZ8kY0NIjVcxfn2-d5vZey-oLdLYtkJU2TUR8PwEi4
if i run it return ok  cancel ok  but if  i open db browser and  look inside of table  the row exist again i try to print the command

```
DELETE FROM ROBOTEST WHERE Symbol='LUNAUSDT' AND ValMedPerc='13.89' AND HowZero='1.0' AND ValRepeat='2.00' AND HowTrade='20' AND OpenPriceTrade='1.4299' AND OkorNot='0' AND GainPercent='1' AND DataOpen='' AND DataClose=''
```

and copy and past in sql execute in db browser and  also here return ok

```
Execution finished without errors.
Result: query executed successfully. Took 0ms, 0 rows affected
At line 1:
DELETE FROM ROBOTEST WHERE Symbol='LUNAUSDT' AND ValMedPerc='13.89' AND HowZero='1.0' AND ValRepeat='2.00' AND HowTrade='20' AND OpenPriceTrade='1.4299' AND OkorNot='0' AND GainPercent='1' AND DataOpen='' AND DataClose=''
```

but not cancel nothing why ?? thanks at all

Comment: It says "0 rows affected", which means that there weren't any rows that matched all the `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: If you change it to `SELECT * FROM ROBOTEST WHERE ...` do you see any output?

Comment: also of interest, does this table have a unique/primary key, or unique index, and if so which columns make up the unique identifier for the row? or does it really require all 10 columns to uniquely identify a row?

Comment: yes have unique id

Comment: is  strange @Barmar because exist in db look the image of my db https://ibb.co/fq15CVn

Comment: The image says that `DataOpen` and `DataClose` are `NULL`, but your query compares them with an empty string. `NULL != ''`. To test for `NULL` you have to write `DataOpen IS NULL`.

Comment: sorry @barman but  how  is try to execute in sql db browser  bur return me syntax error DELETE FROM ROBOTEST WHERE Symbol='LUNAUSDT' AND ValMedPerc='13.89' AND HowZero='1.0' AND ValRepeat='2.00' AND HowTrade='20' AND OpenPriceTrade='1.4299' AND OkorNot='0' AND GainPercent='1' AND DataOpen=IS NULL AND DataClose=IS NULL